# Update TempData after refreshing page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to setup a page that can combine two Excel file into one, and I want to show some message on the page after the file was downloaded, so I use TempData to send the message to my view and use ajax to reload the page after the download was done. However, the message didn't show up but if I click on the refresh button on the browser the will message show up. Here is my code on View.

```
$("#surveyform").on('submit', (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("downloadreport", "surveyForm")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
            location.reload(true);
        }
    });
}));
```

Can someone tell me why the message show up when I click on browser's refresh button but won't show up with my ajax? And how to fix it?

My controller:

```
public ActionResult downloadreport(HttpPostedFileBase file,HttpPostedFileBase file1)
{
    bool missCol = false;
    // .... code to create a excel file (missCol set to true if successful)    
    if (missCol != true)
    {
        TempData["misscol"] = " File download success!";
        return File(newMS, "application/octet-stream", downloadFileName);
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["misscol"] = " Please check your headsource due to missing column!";
        return File(newMS, "application/octet-stream", downloadFileName);
    }    
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var msgtemp = Convert.ToString(TempData["misscol"]);
    TempData["errorcode"] = msgtemp;
    return View();
 }
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using ajax if you then going to just reload the page.

Comment: I'm still learning LOL. At first, I simply just want to use ajax to download the file. But later on I tried to show some message to the user so I use TempData; however, it didn't show and I found out that if I click on the browser's refresh button the message will show up after refreshing the page. So I thought I could add a location.reload code in my ajax.

Comment: Just modify you controller to `return Json("some message");` and chage the script to `success: function (data) { $(someElement).text(data); }` to display the message on the page. (and we cannot possibly comment on your current code when you do not even show the controller code)

Comment: I added my controller code :)

Comment: There is no point using `return File()` - you cannot download a file to the client using ajax (you need to redirect to a GET method that returns the file if you want to download it. If all you want is to display a message that the file was successfully created, see my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks Stephen ! I will think about it again ^^